# why/how is 'this' keyword referring to event object and not global object as I have used 'this' keyword in a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, this

What I did :

1. adding event listeners to all divs of type = "button"
2. when user clicks on any button I recorded the user clicks in an array using 'this' keyword

CODE:

```js
var userClickedPattern = [];

var totalNoOfButtons = document.querySelectorAll("div[type=button]").length;

for (var i = 0; i < totalNoOfButtons; i++){
document.querySelectorAll("div[type=button]")[i].addEventListener("click", userClick);
}

function userClick(){

var userChosenColour = this.id;//why is 'this' referring to event object and not global object

userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);

console.log(userClickedPattern);

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin:  5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;

}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}

/* ANIMATION */
 /* KEYFRAMES */
   @keyframes btn-appearance {
     0% { opacity : 1; }
     100% { opacity: 0; }
   }

   /* animation class */
    .btn-sequence{
      animation-name : btn-appearance;
      animation-duration: 150ms;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


/*jQuery*/
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
/*javascript*/
<script src = "game.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**According to W3Schools theory on 'this' keyword:**
It has different values depending on where it is used:

1. In a method, this refers to the owner object.
2. Alone, this refers to the global object.
3. In a function, this refers to the global object.
4. In a function, in strict mode, this is undefined.
5. In an event, this refers to the element that received the event.

**The Real Question:**
**Explain me why 'this' keyword is referring to event object and not the global object as I have used 'this' keyword in a function userClick()**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: You are using the `this` keyword in a function that is being called in an event listener. So `this` refers to the event listener. If you were to call the function in the global scope `this` would refer to the global object.

Comment: @lejlun to the event currenttarget, not to the event listener.

Comment: @leljun so regarding functions , 'this' keyword will refer according  to where the function is called? am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` in a function is determined by *how the function is called*.

**You** aren't calling the function, you are passing it to `addEventListener` and then the browser is calling it (and assigning the element which is listening as the `this` value).

This is just how `addEventListener` is designed.

---

> xplain me why 'this' keyword is referring to event object and not the global object as I have used 'this' keyword in a function userClick()

Assuming your quote "In a function, this refers to the global object" is accurate, W3Schools is *just plain wrong* (this is not unusual, they aren't good). The place a function declaration is declared has no bearing on the `this` value. They get it right when they contradict themselves with "In an event, this refers to the element that received the event".